# c++: priority_queue: lambda-expression in template-argument

Tags: c++, lambda, std, priority-queue

I am trying to create a `priority_queue` with each element as a 3D vector. The element whose third dimension has the largest value would become the priority element.

Here is my code:

```
   priority_queue< vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, [](vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2){
        return v1[2] > v2[2];
    }> pq{};
```

but I got the following error:

```
error: lambda-expression in template-argument
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant have a lambda (which is an object) in a type template declaration (where a type is needed. Do instead:

```cpp
auto lambda =  [](vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2){
    return v1[2] > v2[2];
};
priority_queue< vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>,decltype(lambda)> pq{lambda};
```

We also need to pass the `lambda` since it is not default constructible.

Form C++20 on, we can do the following:

```cpp
priority_queue< vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>,decltype([](vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2){
    return v1[2] > v2[2];
};
)> pq{};
```

Here there come two new featurs of lambdas into play. First that you can take the type of it directly (formally: In C++17 you cannot have a lambda-expression in unevaluated context) and second that lambdas are default constructible. But right now, that is not yet possible.